# Maximum likelihood estimator for IID exponentials biased

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be IID exponential distributions with parameter $\theta$. I have calculated their maximal likelihood estimator as follows:

The likelihood function is

$$L(\theta) = \theta^n e^{-\theta(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)}$$

Thus the log-likelihood function is

$$l(\theta) = n \ln \theta - \theta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$

Setting $\frac{dl}{d\theta}=0$ and rearranging, we get that

$$\theta_{MLE} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$$

So far, I am agreeing with [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100636/bias-of-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-an-exponential-distribution) on Stats stack exchange.

But then, taking the expectation, $\mathbb{E} \theta_{MLE} = \mathbb{E}\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}x_i}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}1/\theta}=\theta$. Surely this means it is unbiased? The answers there say it is biased and I have been told it should be, and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: why would $\mathbb{E}\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}x_i}$?

Comment: @ZoeAllen Ah, my bad, thanks. Not sure why I didn't spot that.